# Unable to push couchapp with node.couchapp.js

Tags: node.js, couchapp

I'm trying to push a simple couchapp on windows, but I'm dooing sth. wrong.

First I'm installing couchapp using npm:

```
D:\test>npm -g install couchapp
D:\test>npm install couchapp
```

I know that there are two diffrent couchapps, but I'm shurely using the node couchapp:

```
D:\test>couchapp
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
couchapp -- utility for creating couchapps

Usage:
  couchapp <command> app.js http://localhost:5984/dbname

Commands:
  push   : Push app once to server.
  sync   : Push app then watch local files for changes.
  boiler : Create a boiler project.
```

Now I create a couchapp:

couchapp boiler

This creates a app.js and a attachments folder containing a simple couchapp. Now i want to push it to the couchdb:

```
couchapp push app.js http://localhost:5984/test
```

This results in the following error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'app.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test\node_modules\couchapp\bin.js:78:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
```

What am I dooing wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to this but I can maybe help you debug the problem. If you go to this [line](https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js/blob/master/bin.js#L11) and console.log the result of `path.join(process.cwd(), path.normalize(pathname))` then you can find out where couchapp is trying to grab your app.js file.

Also if possible you should check out kanso.js. Last time I created a couchapp (six months ago) kanso.js was a lot better than node.couchapp.js.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I've debuged it: The problem was that the package at npm regestry is out of date (see https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js/pull/41). I'm using now the version from github.